# availability variable in joomla session

Tags: json, session, select, joomla

I have a frameset with the following pages:

```
top.php
left.php
right.html
```

The right.html uses database.php via the json method to access the database and pass through variables. Left.php has select list, generated with items from the database. When selected, the variable is stored in a Joomla session and the right page is refreshed. With the refresh database.php is activated with json.

My question is:

I am able to store the variable in the Joomla session. And when I perform a echo on this variable in left.php, the variable is shown on the screen. However, when I activate database.php the first time, it doesn't pick up the value form the joom session variable. While it is already set in left.php. However, when I select a item from the left.php select box, it does work.

The following code is used in left.php for setting and getting the variables:

```
//If the input select item was selected (when the user has selected a item from                                                     
select box) use that item to fill the Joomla session variable.
if(isset($_POST['PeriodeSelectname'])){
$JaarKwartaal=$_POST['PeriodeSelectname'];
$session->set('JaarKwartaal', $JaarKwartaal);
//echo "<P>session-set=" . $session->get('JaarKwartaal');
}

//if no item of the input select is selected (in case of the first time) the first 
item of the $periodes array to fill the Joomla session variable
if(!isset($_POST['PeriodeSelectname'])){
$session->set('JaarKwartaal', $periodes[0]);
//echo "<P>session-notset=" . $session->get('JaarKwartaal');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Pete

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong:

1. Using Frames.  It's not 1995.  Move on
2. You should set the session variables if you want to read them; right now it seems you're only using POST, which will be unavailable on the second call.

Comment: Thanks for your advice regarding the frames. I will try to solve that. Secondly, when the POST session variable is not available I use the array to fill the Joomla session variable. Furthermore, when I echo the Joomla session variable the variable is shown on the screen. However, in database.php the session variable is empty. When I select a item from the select box, it does work? Any thoughts?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly from what I know; I am assuming that $session is initialized to: $session = JFactory::getSession(); if so, the session variable will be available when you generate your right page after refresh; then you can echo its value and insert it into the javascript / anchors you need it in; this way you complete the circle.  I hope I did understand what you want :-)

Comment: The thing is that I use the getSession() phrase. However, when I echo the results of Joomla session variable within the left.php file, everything is fine. When I try to echo the same joomla session variable in database.php (after it has been set in left.php), it won't show up.